# Definition of field characteristic: Why are these equivalent?

Tags: ring-theory

The characteristic of a field F is defined as either:

a) The number of times one must add the multiplicative identity of F to get the additive identity of F. If the additive identity is never reached the field has characteristic zero.

b) The prime subfield P of F is the intersection of all subfields of F. F has characteristic p if P is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ or characteristic 0 if it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$.

Simply, why are these definitions equivalent?

Comment: Map $\Bbb Z$ to $F$ by $1\mapsto1$ and extend naturally.  The image of $\Bbb Z$ is either isomorphic to $\Bbb Z$ itself, or $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$ for some prime $p$.  In the latter case $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$ is a subfield of $F$ that has no smaller subfield.  In the former case $\Bbb Q$ is a subfield of $F$ which also has no smaller subfield.  Does that help?

Comment: @GregoryGrant Yes, thank you!